# Access variable inside settimeout function

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I am not able to access variable inside settimeout function
i.e in the following example    **setTimeout(pop.hide()), 3000);** here **pop.hide()** doesnt work inside settimeout...

Any solutions..

HTML

```
<div id="logincheck"></div>
```

JS:

```
 function logClick() {
                    var sEmail = $('#username').val();
                    var sPassword = $('#password').val();

                    var pop = $('#logincheck');

                    if (($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) && ($.trim(sPassword).length == 0)) {

                        pop.show();

                        pop.html('Enter EmailId and Password ');
                        setTimeout(pop.hide()), 3000);
                    }
```

Thanks
AB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're **calling** `pop.hide()` and passing its return value into `setTimeout`. Exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`. *(Or rather, you would be, but you have an extra `)` there so it's actually a syntax error — you should be seeing that syntax error in your JavaScript console.)*

You're looking for:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    pop.hide();
}, 3000);
```

There, we define (but don't call) an anonymous function, and pass a reference to that function into `setTimeout`. When the timer expires, that function is called, and it calls `pop.hide()`.

Or since you're using jQuery, you could use its [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
setTimeout($.proxy(pop.hide, pop), 3000);
// or
setTimeout($.proxy(pop, "hide"), 3000);
```

Or if you have ES5's [`bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) available (natively or via an ES5 shim):

```
setTimeout(pop.hide.bind(pop), 3000);
```

Those both essentially do the same thing as our anonymous function above.

Comment: Crowser +1 Nice answer, explained in all possible angles :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use the following (anonymous function)

```
setTimeout(function () {
    pop.hide()
}, 3000);
```

BTW, there is syntax error (an extra `)` ) in your setTimeout code

Answer (score 0):

Assign to pop in logincheck

var pop = $('#logincheck');

Call set timeout this way

```
setTimeout(function(){ pop.hide()} , 3000);
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to make `pop` global (or at least move it outside its nice container [`logClick`]). And a bunch of reasons not to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My mistake, you are absolutely right. Let me change the code. Upvote to your comment by me!

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  pop.hide();
}, 3000);
```